# Uploading images to Windows Server and making them available publicly

Tags: image, iis, windows-server

I am trying to upload images in my windows server VM "hosted on-premise" and make these images available publicly like [www.example.com/imageFolder/cat.png](http://www.example.com/imageFolder/cat.png).

This VM has IIS enabled (I am not sure if IIS is related here) and it is assigned a URL and available publicly.

Aside from any programming languages or frameworks, I just want to know if storing the image in the server and making it available via a link is possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

To clarify further:

I believe what I want is very simple and tedious.

Consider the following workflow:

1. Run an API that has end points to receive images on the server.
2. Store the messages in the server.
3. Return the link that points to the picture.

I want to know the procedure from the windows server side like

1. Do I need to set certain properties on the folder where I will store the images?
2. Do I need to add a site to show the images back to the user?

I am a developer and I am new to the Windows Server & IIS so I may not have all the fundamentals.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Now the example url you show is a useful link that can allow others get this image resource. `I just want to know if storing the image in the server and making it available via a link is possible? ` I can accurately say yes. But I think you can describe more precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: Dear Zhang please check the updated question.  I clarified further from "To clarify further:" onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sample by using ASP.NET MVC5. You can follow this article to upload image in MVC5 application.
[Upload Images on Server Folder Using ASP.NET MVC](https://www.compilemode.com/2018/02/upload-images-on-server-folder-in-asp-net-mvc.html)

Then, I do some changes so that it can display the url of images..

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            Uri requestUri = HttpContext.Request.Url;
            string baseUrl = requestUri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + requestUri.Host + (requestUri.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + requestUri.Port);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                    string link = baseUrl + "/Images/" + file.FileName;
                    ViewBag.FileStatus = "File uploaded successfully.";
                    //Return the url of image
                    ViewBag.FileLink = link;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewBag.FileStatus = "Error while file uploading. Error message is "+e.Message;

                }
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Index.cshtml add this to show url.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-success">
        @ViewBag.FileLink
</div>
```

Don't forget to add a folder named Images to store images. After publishing, you also need to add it in published folder, otherwise error message will show that cannot find folder.
[image]
[image: Published folder]

It works well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thaaaaanks man!! 

I was struggling because I lack some understanding and I followed your code and the solution became obvious to me. 

I did everything before but I was just missing serving the static content and I added this part and solved the problem.